# string pointers not working between functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

I am trying to assign different error messages to the error variable in each case by passing a pointer to the string between functions but for any reason is not working well.

Here is the code:

```
//This function takes a pointer to a char.
int lee(Fecha *f, char *error){ 
    int checking;
    printf("Introduzca una fecha compuesta por día, mes, y año\n");
    checking = scanf("%i %i %i", &f->day, &f->month, &f->year);
    printf("%d\n", checking);
    switch (checking){
        case 0:
            //The message is assigned to the space where error points to.
            *error = "Formato de fecha incorrecto. El día debe ser un entero."; 
        break;
        case 1:
            *error = "Formato de fecha incorrecto. El mes debe ser un entero.";
        break;
        case 2:
            *error = "Formato de fecha incorrecto. El año debe ser un entero.";
        break;
    }
    return (checking == 3);
}

int main(){
    Fecha f;
    //error is declared like a pointer
    char * error; 
    int ret;
    //The pointer is passed to the function as argument.
    ret = lee(&f, error); 
    printf("%s", error);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
user@console:~/$ ./Sesion1 
Introduzca una fecha compuesta por día, mes, y año (o 0 0 0 para terminar el programa)
23 dfgadkfhgsñdgh 5
1
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: take a look at `*error` and think about what that means.  what are you assigning to it and how does it work memory wise?

Comment: Yeah.. looking for the malloc for error.... failing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to make an output to the string, you need to pass pointer to your char*, so you need to pass error as char**.

So the function will be

```
int lee(Fecha *f, char **error){ 
    int checking;
    printf("Introduzca una fecha compuesta por día, mes, y año\n");
    checking = scanf("%i %i %i", &f->day, &f->month, &f->year);
    printf("%d\n", checking);
    switch (checking){
        case 0:
            //The message is assigned to the space where error points to.
            *error = "Formato de fecha incorrecto. El día debe ser un entero."; 
        break;
        case 1:
            *error = "Formato de fecha incorrecto. El mes debe ser un entero.";
        break;
        case 2:
            *error = "Formato de fecha incorrecto. El año debe ser un entero.";
        break;
    }
    return (checking == 3);
}

int main(){
    Fecha f;
    //error is declared like a pointer
    char * error; 
    int ret;
    //The pointer is passed to the function as argument.
    ret = lee(&f, &error); 
    printf("%s", error);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you should consider not leaving pointers without value after declaration like you did with char* error in main().

The problem is, when you have a pointer that is not initialized and then you forget to give it a value or something like this, it can point anywhere within your application memory (or beyond it). Virtual memory protects you from reading and writing to others applications memory (generally speaking), but you can have a case where the pointer happens to point to some data inside your application. And if you then use this pointer to write or read, you will have unpredictable result, ranging from just displaying erroneous data to corrupting data or crashing application, which you obviously do not want.

Comment: Thanks for the response (thanks to all in fact). Maybe that situatuion of unpredictable results may be resolved initialized the error pointer to NULL? `char * error = NULL;`

Comment: No problem, everyone needs to start somewhere. Just make sure you understand all these things with pointers and memory before moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a pointer to your function output parameters. Since your output parameter is `char*`, the pointer to it is `char**`.

To fix, change the corresponding lines to:

```
int lee(Fecha *f, char **error);
// ...
ret = lee(&f, &error);
```